# How price model approximations can be calculated?

Tags: technical-analysis

Sometimes I see a Bitcoin price model such as [this](https://www.tradingview.com/script/dFXcChjc-Bitcoin-Price-Model-v1-1/).
I'm quite inspired by these approximations and their beautifulness, but the problem is I have no idea how these price models can be calculated. I know this may be a quite elementary question, but I'd like to know what ways possibly I can think of to get these approximations.

> TopPriceLine = exp(12.1929372+pow(T,0.337559402))/stock

Comment: Generally these are *curve fitting exercises* where someone assumes an expression of the form exp($\alpha$+pow(T,$\beta$)/stock and then finds $\alpha$ and $\beta$ that make the curve fit the available past data. For example they might use the *least squares method* to find the values. Of course a weakness is that future data may not necessarily fit the equation without some changes to the parameters or to the equation itself, so it is a backward looking method.

Comment: What would be impressive would be if the user used a curve to predict future trajectory and the price actually follows that trajectory. This is not the case here as we are fitting the curve after the fact. Finding the mathematical functional forms aren't really that useful, but you can explore the area of symbolic regression for this.